# FFMPEG output upload to AWS S3 instead of local disk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ffmpeg

Currently, I'm outputting the result of FFmpeg process in the file locally on disk using the command

```
ffmpeg -i myfile.mp4 -an -crf 20 -vf crop=200:200 -s 800x600 newfile.mp4
```

> Is it possible to store result `newfile.mp4` directly on the amazon s3
> bucket without saving the file locally? If so and if my s3 bucket
> address is `s3://my.test.bucket` how would you do it?

What have I tried so far?

```
ffmpeg -i myfile.mp4 -an -crf 20 -vf crop=200:200 -s 800x600 | s3://my.test.bucket
```

> |: Invalid argument

```
ffmpeg -i myfile.mp4 -an -crf 20 -vf crop=200:200 -s 800x600 pipe: s3://my.test.bucket
```

> Unable to find a suitable output format for 'pipe:' pipe:: Invalid
> argument

Comment: The command would be `ffmpeg ... -f mp4 pipe:1 | aws s3 cp - s3://...`. Not that it matters, creating a mp4 file requires seeking, and piping output doesn't allow for seeking, so this isn't generally possible.

Comment: Did you try using an S3 pre-signed PUT or POST URL for the desired S3 object in place of `pipe: s3://my.test.bucket`?

Comment: @jarmod no I did not, this is new for me. Can you please provide more info, how the ffmpeg command would look like, do I need to create pre-signed url automatically or I can create through aws console?

Comment: @AnonCoward, so if I understand you there is no way to store the output file (MP4)  from ffmpeg into s3 bucket?

Comment: Investigate using ffmpeg to write to an HTTP URL or just try what I suggested. I believe that ffmpeg can write to an HTTP URL, so if you use the awscli you can generate a pre-signed HTTP URL to PUT the object to S3 and use that URL. Try it.

Comment: @jarmod: That has the same basic issue as a pipe, the PUT/POST handler in ffmpeg doesn't support seeking, and on top of that, the awscli has no method to generate anything other than a GET presigned URL.

Comment: @user1765862 Correct, you need a container format that doesn't require seeking to avoid saving the entire media file to memory or disk before upload.  One such option is `ismv` instead of `mp4` for the `-f` option.  It's similar to an mp4 file, and may or may not work depending on what your playback engine supports.  Or another container type all together like `ts`.

Comment: @AnonCoward you're right on the awscli (would have to use an SDK to pre-sign a PUT). I saw your earlier comment about seeking and didn't realize the significance of it at the time. Interesting, I shall have to read more.